# How to perform noise cancelation in Python using two numpy arrays which are not predefined?

Tags: python, signals, noise, noise-reduction

I was wondering how to go about performing noise cancelation on two incoming audio streams of data that I put into two NumPy arrays. One of them contains noise from a USB mic and the other one is from two external microphones which I concatenated which captures the user's voice as well as noise. I have searched the web and found modules such as noisereduce and Padasip. But the problem is I'm working on a Raspberry Pi 4 and it doesn't support noisereduce and I'm having trouble getting Padasip to work. I'm really new to signal processing, so I was wondering which algorithm would be best? And how to implement it in my current situation? If you need more details I will gladly provide them.

Here is the code I'm currently using to capture the audio from the two mics which I concatenate and the noise from the usb mic. As well as my current noise cancelation function I'm trying to implement...

```
def capture(self, q, index):
    print("Capturing audio...")
    frames = []
    p = pyaudio.PyAudio()
    stream = p.open(format=self.format,
                    channels=self.channels,
                    rate=self.rate,
                    input=True,
                    input_device_index=index,
                    frames_per_buffer=self.chunk)

    for i in range(0, int(self.rate / self.chunk * self.record_seconds)):
        data = stream.read(self.chunk)
        data_int = list(struct.unpack(str(2 * self.chunk) + 'B', data))
        frames.extend(data_int)

    print("Done capturing audio!!!")
    stream.stop_stream()
    stream.close()
    p.terminate()
    
    q.put(frames)

def record(self):
    print("Recording!!!")
    self.rled.on()
    
    q = Queue()
    processes = []
    nd = []
    m1d = []
    m2d = []
    
    for i in range(2, 5):
        p = Process(target=self.capture, args=(q, i,))
        processes.append(p)
        p.start()
    
    count = 1
    for p in processes:
        count += 1
        ret = q.get()
        if count == 2: nd.extend(ret)
        elif count == 3: m1d.extend(ret)
        else: m2d.extend(ret)
        
    for p in processes:
        p.join()
         
    noise_data = np.array(nd, dtype='b')[::2] + 128
    bsmic_data = np.array(m1d, dtype='b')[::2] + 128
    jmic_data = np.array(m2d, dtype='b')[::2] + 128
    mic_data = np.add(bsmic_data, jmic_data)
    
    self.rled.off()
    self.cancel(noise_data, mic_data)
        
def cancel(self, noise, mic):
    #eliminates as much noise as possible from original stream
    print("Peforming noise cancelation...")
```